# Will a gigabit switch improve in-network transfer speeds without a gigabit router?

Tags: switch, gigabit-ethernet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will using a 10/100 router stunt gigabit switch speeds for an internal network?](https://superuser.com/questions/75003/will-using-a-10-100-router-stunt-gigabit-switch-speeds-for-an-internal-network)

I have a 10/100 router but am considering buying a gigabit switch to add to the network to increase transfer speeds between computers and network storage devices.  Will the router have any negative effect on the transfer speeds?  Or will the speeds increase as long as everything is hooked up through the new switch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/75003/will-using-a-10-100-router-stunt-gigabit-switch-speeds-for-an-internal-network and http://superuser.com/questions/63541/100mbps-and-gigabit-switch-on-the-same-lan

Comment: 6 years, 1 month after this was asked:  The slowest part of the system will determine your speed from end to end.

Answer (score 1):

If you are replacing the 10/100 router with the switch AND the components support Gigabit, yes, the speeds will increase substantially.

Generally, any given communication on the network will move at the speed of the slowest system involved in the communication. If a computer with a 100Mbps connection is trying to access a file from a NAS running at Gigabit, the communication will be governed by the capabilities of the slower computer.